# django startproject - Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to run the site-packages from a new location which installed properly using `pip install --target /opt/common/external/python_modules`

I then set my PATH to point to `/opt/common/external/python_modules/django/bin/` and my PYTHONPATH to reference the new location at `/opt/common/external/python_modules`

When trying to start a project I get the below Traceback.

```
[user@server ~]$ django-admin.py startproject itam_api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/common/external/python_modules/django/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/opt/common/external/python_modules/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/common/external/python_modules/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/common/external/python_modules/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/opt/common/external/python_modules/django/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/common/external/python_modules/django/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a pip uninstall on all packages, and set my umask as 022.  After I reinstalled django it works properly.